# Where does "." (dot) come from when using PHP ´scandir´

Tags: php, scandir

I'm a bit confused.
I'm building a PHP function to loop out images in a specified dir.

**PHP**

```
$dir = "bilder/".$objekt[0]['objekt_nr']."/thumbnail/";
$thumbnails = scandir($dir);

print_r($thumbnails);

foreach ($thumbnails as $value) {
   echo "<img src='".$dir.$value. "'>";
}
```

**array**

```
(
[0] => .
[1] => ..
[2] => bjornc.jpg
[3] => test_bild3.jpg
)
```

**HTML**

```
<img src='bilder/22159/thumbnail/.'>
<img src='bilder/22159/thumbnail/..'>
<img src='bilder/22159/thumbnail/bjornc.jpg'>
<img src='bilder/22159/thumbnail/test_bild3.jpg'>
```

How can i get rid of theese dots?
I guess it´s the directorie dots..

**UPDATE**

The most easy way was found in php.net manual

```
$thumbnails = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
```

Comment: In UNIX / Linux , `.` represents current directory ( while `..` represent parent directory ). They exist in every folder. Feel free to filter them as mentioned in PHP manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dot directory is the *current* directory. Dot-dot is the *parent* directory.

If you want to create a list of files in a directory you should really skip those two, or really *any* directory starting with a leading dot (on POSIX systems like Linux and OSX those are supposed to be hidden directories).

You can do that by simply check if the first character in the file name is a dot, and if it is just skip it (i.e. you `continue` the loop).

Comment: Thank you. I found ´array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));´ to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip it by using `in_array` as

```
foreach ($thumbnails as $value) {
    if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))) {
        echo "<img src='" . $dir . $value . "'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found ´array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));´ to be helpful.

Comment: yaa you can use it too!! http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php here is the example of it

Answer (score 1):

they are directory and parent directory, they can be removed with following code:

```
    <?php
    $dir = "downloads/";
    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dir_handler = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dir_handler)) !== false){
                if ($file!="."&&$file!="..") {
                    //your code
                }
            }
        closedir($dir_handler);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I found ´array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));´ to be helpful.

Comment: This is also correct please remove NOTE part from your code!!

Comment: @Saty removed that note part

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
foreach ($thumbnails as $value) {
   if ( $value !='.' && $value !='..')
   {
     echo "<img src='".$dir.$value. "'>";
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a specific file type, such as images, you are better off using [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).
It allows you to pass a pattern of extensions.
This way you can be sure you fetch only the files you are looking for.

Example for multiple file types, `.jpg` and `.png`

```
$dir = "bilder/".$objekt[0]['objekt_nr']."/thumbnail/";
$files = glob("*.{jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

print_r($files);
```

> GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

Example for a single file type, `.jpg`

```
$dir = "bilder/".$objekt[0]['objekt_nr']."/thumbnail/";
$files = glob("*.jpg");

print_r($files);
```

Answer (score 0):

@joachim Pileborg answer is correct, By the way you can also use glob()

```
$thumbnails = glob("$dir/*.jpg");

foreach ($thumbnails as $value) {
   echo "<img src='$value'/>";
}
```