# Loop returning some weird dots

Tags: php, loops, directory

My dropdown with folders is returning dots even if i check if there are no one.

https://prnt.sc/q5q5rd

Code:

```
$d = dir("content/client_areas/");
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
{
    if (is_dir($entry) && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
        ?><option value="<?php echo $entry;?>"><?php echo $entry;?></option><?php
}

$d->close();
```

I can't figure out why i get these dots.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does "." (dot) come from when using PHP ´scandir´](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149598/where-does-dot-come-from-when-using-php-%c2%b4scandir%c2%b4)

Comment: I don't use array for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your `if` correctly with braces `{ }`. Without them, the statement after the `if` is not part of the `if` and is not constrained by the result of the expression:

```
if (is_dir("content/client_areas/$entry") && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
    ?><option value="<?php echo $entry;?>"><?php echo $entry;?></option><?php
}
```

Also, `$entry` will not be the full path so `is_dir()` will always fail.  Add `content/client_areas/` or whatever path.

If you were to construct the output in PHP with a terminating semicolon `;` it would work as expected:

```
if (is_dir("content/client_areas/$entry") && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..') 
    echo '<option value="'.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</option>';
```

Or [Alternative Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#control-structures.alternative-syntax):

```
if (is_dir("content/client_areas/$entry") && $entry != '.' && $entry != '..'):
    ?><option value="<?php echo $entry;?>"><?php echo $entry;?></option><?php
endif;
```

Comment: I already tried this,in this case i get nothing: https://prnt.sc/q5q9o8

Comment: Thanks so much! ^-^

Comment: If the very first condition of the `if` was failing, how was _anything_ being generated in the options list??

Comment: @PatrickQ Because the curly braces were missing and ALL entries were being shown as if the `if` was not even there.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Gotcha.  That's actually a pretty interesting case then.  I'm assuming that this is because the break from PHP control that happens?  Because if a single line were placed under the `if` _within_ PHP control, it _would_ be part of (and the _only_ part of) the `if` condition.  While I'm not a fan of the control-break style being used by OP, I can definitely understand the confusion if OP is used to single-line conditions.

Comment: @PatrickQ:  yes, it's because of no `;` when breaking out of PHP https://3v4l.org/DQn3Z